# Openrefine: cross cluster two dataset

Tags: cluster-analysis, openrefine

I've got two datasets with titles and other informations, but in dataset A I have titles, in dataset B I have titles and URL. 
I have to put the URL in dataset A from dataset B. Some titles are the same in A and B, some others are not, some others are slightly different (and here comes the problem).

So I need to merge and cluster at the same time those who are similar. I know that I can reconcile with DBpedia, but what I need is to "reconcile" between the two dataset.
Is it possible in some way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reconcile-csv](http://okfnlabs.org/reconcile-csv/) application (it's not plugin for OpenRefine, but standalone program that runs local reconciliation API server).

Export dataset *B* as csv with first row as column names, then start reconcile-csv, using *URL* as *id* column and *name* as *search* column:

`java -Xmx2g -jar reconcile-csv-0.1.2.jar <CSV-File> <Search Column> <ID Column>`

Then open dataset *A* and add `http://localhost:8000/reconcile` as reconciliation service. After reconciliation, `cell.recon.match.id` for each reconciled cell will contain URL.

Comment: afaik reconcile-csv just let you import the id from the dataset B. Then you will need to use the cell.cross function to actually import the URL

Comment: @magdmartin I suggest using URL as id, if urls are unique.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer! Sorry if I reply you so late. I tried a little bit with reconcile-csv but, not being so experienced, I had some problems in understanding how it works. I'll try it now your instructions, thanks!